# What was the mother's secret?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, outlaws-and-angels

I refer to the film [Outlaws and Angels (2016)](http://gb.imdb.com/title/tt3491962/) wherein everyone in the household had...

> a nasty secret, all of which were revealed as the story progressed.

...but what was the mother's (the character Ada Tildon)? It either went by too fast for me or she was innocent. And hence I don't know if she got killed in the end or her innocence kept her alive?

> The ending is ambiguous. It's not clear if the mother was killed so as
>  to not share the loot or for vengeance or was left to live.

Was the mother innocent, if not what was her secret?

Comment: Not having seen the movie, I can't tell if this is one or two questions; if these questions are separate, please ask them separately. On this site, it's better to have multiple specific questions than one general one.